# Surplus space between the variable and dot in Angular, how can I clean up it?

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-template-variable

I have a condition block with `ng-container` in my Angular html template. The rendered html contains unexplained space for me, how can I work it around?

The template part:

```
                         <span>
                            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="languageService.currentLang">
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngSwitchCase="'en'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameEn}}
                                </ng-container>
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngSwitchCase="'ru'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameRu}}
                                </ng-container>
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngSwitchCase="'tt'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameTt}}
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]">
                                <!--<a [routerLink]="['/subject', accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.id, 'view']">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.name}}</a>-->
                                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="languageService.currentLang">&
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'en'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameEn}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'ru'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameRu}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'tt'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameTt}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                            .</span>
                            <span
                                jhiTranslate="businesslogic.shop.subscription.platform">Platform Subscription</span>
```

And the final html, that was generated is:

```
<div> 
   <span> <!----> <!----><!---->Mental arithmetics  <!----> <!---->  <!----><!----> <!---->&amp; <!----><!---->Speed reading  <!----> <!---->   .</span> 
   <span jhitranslate="businesslogic.shop.subscription.platform">Platform Subscription.</span> 
</div>
```

Why do I have spaces between ...reading and dot?

UPD.

I tried not to use `span`, but I still us `ng-container` and still getting the spaces:

```
<div *ngIf="accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]">
                                <!--<a [routerLink]="['/subject', accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.id, 'view']">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.name}}</a>-->
                                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="languageService.currentLang">
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'en'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameEn}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'ru'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameRu}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container
                                        *ngSwitchCase="'tt'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[0]?.nameTt}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-container>
                                <ng-container *ngIf="accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]">
                                    <!--<a [routerLink]="['/subject', accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.id, 'view']">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subject?.name}}</a>-->
                                    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="languageService.currentLang">&
                                        <ng-container
                                            *ngSwitchCase="'en'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameEn}}
                                        </ng-container>
                                        <ng-container
                                            *ngSwitchCase="'ru'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameRu}}
                                        </ng-container>
                                        <ng-container
                                            *ngSwitchCase="'tt'">{{accessSubscriptionPlan.subjects[1]?.nameTt}}
                                        </ng-container>
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-container>
                                .
                                <span
                                    jhiTranslate="businesslogic.shop.subscription.platform">Platform Subscription</span>
                            </div>
```

and the output is:

```
<div> <!----> <!----><!---->Mental arithmetics  <!----> <!---->  <!----> . <span jhitranslate="businesslogic.shop.subscription.platform">Platform Subscription.</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with that the `span` is an inline element. That's why the parser keeps every white-space in it.

So every new line and tab and space will be trimed into 1 space.

Try using other element like div or so.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/96c9ccc81a14752fc4cf5c70f5042c693bd50f19/packages/compiler/src/ml_parser/html_whitespaces.ts) is the current version of the code that eliminates the whitespaces.

Comment: I added a link to the part of compiler if you interested.

Comment: I tried to leave them in div and still getting the spaces: <div> <!----> <!----><!---->Mental arithmetics  <!----> <!---->  <!----> . <span jhitranslate="businesslogic.shop.subscription.platform">Platform Subscription.</span> </div>

Comment: I have updated the question with more detailed explanation, what I'm getting without span, inside div, with ng-container tags only.

Comment: and what is the reason of repetitive <!-- --> ?

Comment: Try to update the html to look like this: `<div><!-- \n ...` instead of `<div>\n<!-- ...`.